# Extract data from an Array

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have an array DetailsArray in VB.NET which contains the result of a LINQ query. I have shown below the values of the array. i need to get the "ProjectID" from the array and assign it to 'ProjID' variable

> DetailsArray (0){Name =
>   "TestProject1", ProjectID = 10}

```
 Dim ProjID as Integer = DetailsArray(??)
```

How would I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing the values of the *first* element of the array (`DetailsArray(0)`), not of the whole array (`DetailsArray`).

To get to the value of the `ProjectID` property in the first element of the array:

```
Dim ProjID as Integer = DetailsArray(0).ProjectID
```

Comment: Great thanks. Thats the whole array, It only has those elements.